# Is there a way to vectorize this procedure in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a simple stock portfolio simulation I am trying to model, but despite some attempts, I cannot figure out a way to vectorize this.  Maybe it's not possible, but I wanted to see if anyone out there had any thoughts.

My sticking point is that the shares on a given day are a function of the account value and stock price of two days previous.  But the account value on a day is a function of the previous day's account value and today's number of shares and stock price change.  So there is a back and forth relationship between shares and account value that I can't think of a way to vectorize, and thus my only solution below is the for loop below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
stats = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0,10))

stats['Acct Val'] = 0.0
stats['Shares'] = 0.0
stats['Stock Px'] = pd.Series([23,25,24,26,22,23,25,25,26,24],index=stats.index)
# Wgt is the percentage of the account value that should be invested in the stock on a given day
stats['Wgt'] = pd.Series([0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.0,],index=stats.index)
stats['Daily PNL'] = 0.0
# Start the account value at $10,000.00
stats.ix[0:1, 'Acct Val'] = 10000.0
stats.ix[0:1, 'Wgt'] = 0
for date_loc in range(2, len(stats.index)):
    # Keep shares the same unless 'wgt' column changes
    if stats.at[date_loc,'Wgt'] != stats.at[date_loc-1,'Wgt']:
        # Rebalanced shares are based on the acct value and stock price two days before
        stats.at[date_loc,'Shares'] = stats.at[date_loc-2,'Acct Val'] * stats.at[date_loc,'Wgt'] / stats.at[date_loc-2,'Stock Px']
    else:
        stats.at[date_loc,'Shares'] = stats.at[date_loc-1,'Shares']
    # Daily PNL is simply the shares owned on a day times the change in stock price from the previous day to the next
    stats.at[date_loc,'Daily PNL'] = stats.at[date_loc,'Shares'] * (stats.at[date_loc,'Stock Px'] - stats.at[date_loc-1,'Stock Px'])
    # Acct value is yesterday's acct value plus today's PNL
    stats.at[date_loc,'Acct Val'] = stats.at[date_loc-1,'Acct Val'] + stats.at[date_loc,'Daily PNL']


In [44]: stats
Out[44]:
       Acct Val      Shares  Stock Px  Wgt   Daily PNL
0  10000.000000    0.000000        23  0.0    0.000000
1  10000.000000    0.000000        25  0.0    0.000000
2   9782.608696  217.391304        24  0.5 -217.391304
3  10217.391304  217.391304        26  0.5  434.782609
4   9728.260870  122.282609        22  0.3 -489.130435
5   9885.451505  157.190635        23  0.4  157.190635
6  10199.832776  157.190635        25  0.4  314.381271
7  10199.832776   85.960448        25  0.2    0.000000
8  10285.793224   85.960448        26  0.2   85.960448
9  10285.793224    0.000000        24  0.0   -0.000000

In [45]:
```

EDIT:  11:01 PM October 19, 2013:

I tried using foobarbecue's code but I couldn't get there:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
stats = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0,10))
stats['Acct Val'] = 10000.0
stats['Shares'] = 0.0
stats['Stock Px'] = pd.Series([23,25,24,26,22,23,25,25,26,24],index=stats.index)
# Wgt is the percentage of the account value that should be invested in the stock on a given day
stats['Wgt'] = pd.Series([0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.2,0.0,],index=stats.index)
stats['Daily PNL'] = 0.0
# Start the account value at $10,000.00
#stats.ix[0:1, 'Acct Val'] = 10000.0
stats.ix[0:1, 'Wgt'] = 0

def function1(df_row):
    #[stuff you want to do when Wgt changed]
    df_row['Shares'] = df_row['Acct Val'] * df_row['Wgt2ahead'] / df_row['Stock Px']
    return df_row

def function2(df_row):
    #[stuff you want to do when Wgt did not change]
    df_row['Shares'] = df_row['SharesPrevious']
    return df_row

#Find where the Wgt column changes
stats['WgtChanged']=stats.Wgt.diff() <> 0 # changed ">" to "<>"
#Using boolean indexing, choose all rows where Wgt changed and apply a function
stats['Wgt2ahead'] = stats['Wgt'].shift(-2)
stats = stats.apply(lambda df_row: function1(df_row) if df_row['WgtChanged'] == True else df_row, axis=1)
stats['Shares'] = stats['Shares'].shift(2)
#Likewise, for rows where Wgt did not change
stats['SharesPrevious'] = stats['Shares'].shift(1)
stats = stats.apply(lambda df_row: function2(df_row) if df_row['WgtChanged'] == False else df_row, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(df_row):
    [stuff you want to do when Wgt changed]

def function2(df_row):
    [stuff you want to do when Wgt did not change]

#Find where the Wgt column changes
stats['WgtChanged']=stats.Wgt.diff() > 0
#Using boolean indexing, choose all rows where Wgt changed and apply a function
stats[stats['WgtChanged']].apply(function1, axis=1)
#Likewise, for rows where Wgt did not change
stats[~stats['WgtChanged']].apply(function2, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your method and got stuck with the fact that in function 1, it needs to compute today's acct value by adding today's PNL to yesterday's acct value.  I don't see how to do that since function1 operates on a single row at a time. Maybe I'm missing something.  My attempt at using your code is posted in the edit of the question above.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My reading of the question was incomplete. Seems like the remaining issue here is that your output for a cell depends on other columns AND other rows. I think this can be accomplished by breaking it up into a multi-step process (.apply with axis=0 and then again with axis=1)... you may need an intermediate column or two. Don't have time to figure it out right now but will come back to this if you're still having trouble and no one else figures it out.